# How to get an IBuffer from an IRandomAccessStream

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

If I have a IRandomAccessStream object, how do I create a IBuffer object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way I found was to go via MemoryStream.GetWindowsRuntimeBuffer :

```
IRandomAccessStream stream = ...;

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    memoryStream.Capacity = (int)stream.Size;
    var ibuffer = memoryStream.GetWindowsRuntimeBuffer();
    await stream.ReadAsync(ibuffer, (uint)stream.Size, InputStreamOptions.None).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Is this your workaround or did you find the solution immediately and posted it?

Comment: This is what I ended up using, I thought I'd share.

Comment: You should not do `.AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false)`, that's a native async operation, so there's no point trying to continue on called thread - that won't happen!